# Jbpm peristence to Mysql external database

Tags: jboss, drools, jbpm

using jbpm 7.43.1

I am new to Business Central, jbpm and drools and I am trying to have the engine work with a mysql database. I am having issues setting up the persistence of the data objects and using the ExecuteSQL in the business processes. I thought setting up the database connection and accessing the table using the built in data sets and data sources functionality would make this easier. Are there any resources available to help me with this set up? I can access the data fine using data sets and data sources but the project is unable to find it when deploying.

In the project settings I have:

```
Persistence unit name = dataSourceName
Persistence data source = java:jboss/datasources/dataSourceName
Marshalling Strategies name = new org.drools.persistence.jpa.marshaller.JPAPlaceholderResolverStrategy("dataSourceName", classLoader)
```

Errors I am finding in the logs:

```
ERROR [org.kie.server.services.jbpm.JbpmKieServerExtension] (default task-6) Error when creating container optimusRules_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT by extension jBPM KIE Server extension: java.lang.RuntimeException: [Error: could not create constructor: null]
....
[Near : {... new org.drools.persistence.jpa.mar ....}]
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: datasources/netcoolDev -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.dataSourceName
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:jboss/datasources/dataSourceName]
```

Answer (score 0):

You datasource is pointing incorrectly, please update persistent.xml with transaction type as jta and jta datasource node correctly.